# Set default value to an image "Public Property"

Tags: vb.net, properties, user-controls

I try to set default value to an image `Public Property` of a `UserControl`. I tried to do that with a variable but I get an error `Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.`

```
Private Image_ As Image = My.Resources.MyImage
<Category("Appearance")> <DisplayName("Image")> <DefaultValue(Image_)> <Description("...")>
Public Property Image As Image
    Get
        Return NestedControl.Image
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Image)
        NestedControl.Image = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I also tried to set default value like this `<DefaultValue(GetType(Image), "My.Resources.MyImage")>` but when I do reset to `UserControl`'s property it turns to "None"!!!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute` does not support this, you can use the old-style **Reset**PropertyName and **ShouldSerialize**PropertyName methods to achieve the same function.

This is documented in [Defining Default Values with the ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods).

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class MyUserControl
    Private Image_ As Image = My.Resources.MyImage

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ResetImage() ' set default
    End Sub

    <Category("Appearance")> <DisplayName("Image")> <Description("...")>
    Public Property Image As Image
        Get
            Return NestedControl.Image
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Image)
            NestedControl.Image = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub ResetImage()
        If Image IsNot Nothing Then Image.Dispose()
        Image = Image_
    End Sub

    Public Function ShouldSerializeImage() As Boolean
        Return (Image IsNot Image_)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much my friend!!! Thank you for the link too! :)